# MVC 5 . I want to hide Action & controller name from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm facing problem to hide action name controller name. I searched lot of articles but still I cannot get satisfactory answer. I can hide only controller name.

e.g.

```
www.mynewsite.com/Account/Registration
www.mynewsite.com/home/about
```

but I want same url like `www.mynewsite.com` only for all. Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: Short answer - its not possible

Comment: You can use Routing

Comment: @rahul :- Just tell me is it possible. If yes I will search . because many people tell it is not possible. So Just tell me Is it possible or not?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can it be not possible with *slug*?

Comment: @Div, OP has stated they want `www.mynewsite.com` for everything :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke :- I have done this functionality in asp.net. I have just started work in mvc from 15 days so I am very fresher in mvc . for this reason I am asking

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh yes, definitely not possible :)

Comment: handle all clicks of your <A> tags.... and load all your pages through ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick using java script after loading your page.

just try within your `document.ready` function

`window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");`

Note: URL will be visible before loading your page.

Comment: @santosh thank you for your suggestion. It is working. But my URL is blinking Is there any solution ?

Comment: @vijukoli As I mentioned in note URL will be visible before loading your page after it will be change thatswhy it is blinking.