# Modify url path without redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can modify url path like`example.com/blog_id=4&comment_id=5`
to just `example.com` without redirection.
so the content gonna be of that long url but after 
loading page it modifies it to that short url.

Comment: You would usually start by writing some code.  Have you tried that?  It would improve your question immensely if you posted it

Comment: .htaccess is the answer google it and you'll find answers

Comment: use ajax to load that page in the homepage

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305628/842112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions seems like [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) good usage:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/blog_id=\d+&comment_id=\d+$ example.com [NC,L]
```

You can also use JS [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for that:

```
var stateObj = {blog_id: 4, comment_id: 5};
history.pushState(stateObj, "", "example.com");
history.replaceState(stateObj, "", "example.com");
```

Difference: when `pushState` and clicking back button you will be redirected to previous URL while `replaceState` will redirect to actual previous page that you visited before using `replaceState`

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript `pushstate` to clear your URL after page load.

`window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");`